# How can I make this work using a nested if-else when detecting the type of data of the inputted data using python

Tags: python-3.x, types, nested-if

I would like to know how can I make the python program work when using if else statement and detecting what kind of data type is the data inputted.

Here's the code that I have inputted based on my knowledge (sorry I'm a newbie):

```
FullName = input("Enter your Full Name: ")
data = input("Enter a data: ")
if type(eval(data)) == float and int:
    if type(eval(data)) == float:
        print("Hello,", FullName + ". Your inputted data", data, "is a type of Float!")
    else:
        print("Hello,", FullName + ". Your inputted data", data, "is a type of Integer!")
else:
    print("Hello,", FullName + ". Your inputted data", data, "is a type of String!")
```

If you can correct my work, feel free, I would much appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. you probably meant `float or int` not `float and int`
2. you cant use and/or that way you need to say `type(eval(data)) == float or type(eval(data)) ==  int` else you get weird behavior because the or operator compares `something == something` (which is a boolean) with an other type thats not a boolean.
3. you dont realy need a nested if-statement here if you use elif
   ( if int ... elif float ... else )